# What are the "markers" in Marauders #20

Tags: marvel, comics, x-men

I just finished Marauders #20.

In this issue, Marauders try to guess how many knives Storm wears. All participants will owed a "marker" to the winner.

What is a marker in this context ?

[image: Kate talking about markers]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A "[marker](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/marker)" is a credit that is owed in the form of an IOU.

> (US, slang) Synonym of IOU, an informal record of a debt.

She's basically saying that instead of offering a tangible prize, the winning guesser will get a (small) favour from the others that they can call in at a later date.

Comment: Interesting. I've not heard this meaning before. Is there any info on where or with whom this slang is popular?

Comment: @trlkly https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/owe-someone-a-marker.3109550/ "It featured prominently in the plot of the movie (and musical) 'Guys and Dolls', for example, and there was even an old Shirley Temple movie called "Little Miss Marker" where a father leaves his child as a marker for his gambling debt, promising to come back for her when he has the money." so popular among 1930-50s US gamblers?